# Using Python 3.7 and Webdriver, how do I find a specific button inside a "<li", which is in turn found inside a "<div" element?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am including portions of the HTML below. I believe I have found the larger element using the command:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="day-number-4"]')`

That div ID is unique on the web page, and the command above did not create an exception nor error.
The HTML code that defines that element is:

`<div id="day-number-4" class="c-schedule-calendar__class-schedule-content tabcontent js-class-schedule-content u-is-none u-is-block" data-index="3">`

Now, the hard part. Inside that div element are a number of "<li"'s that take the form of:

`<li tabindex="0" class="row c-schedule-calendar__class-schedule-listitem-wrapper c-schedule-calendar__workout-schedule-list-item" data-index="0" data-workout-id="205687" data-club-id="229">`

and then followed a clickable button in this format:
  `<button class="c-btn-outlined class-action" data-class-action="book-class" data-class-action-step="class-action-confirmation" data-workout-id="205687" data-club-id="229" data-waitlistable="true"><span class="c-btn__label">Join Waitlist</span></button>`

I always want to click on the 3rd button inside that <div element. The only thing unique would be the data-index, which starts at 0 for the 1st <li", and 2 for the 3rd

So I want to find the clickable button that will follow this HTML code:

`<li tabindex="0" class="row c-schedule-calendar__class-schedule-listitem-wrapper c-schedule-calendar__workout-schedule-list-item" data-index="2" data-workout-id="206706" data-club-id="229">`

I cannot search on data-index as "data-index="2"" appears many times on the web page.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. I used multiple searches within the specific element using this code:

```
Day_of_Timeslot = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="day-number-4"]')
Precise_Timeslot = Day_of_Timeslot.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[@data-index='1']")
Actual_Button = Precise_Timeslot.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@data-class-action='book-class']").click()
```